# How can get value of some component of jsp page in scriplet tag?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

I am setting 'Id' in a hidden field. what should I do to get this value in Scriptlet?

I have this field

```
<html:hidden name="ConfigForm" property="ConfigId" styleId="ConfigId"/>
```

i want this field's value in my scriptlet which has some line of code like this

```
<% Integer ConfigId =1;
  ConfigDTO = getConfig(ConfigId, null); %>
```

For now im passing hardcoded ConfgiId but I need to replace it with hidden field value. –

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Perhaps with some code and what you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: May be you get using---

request.getAttribute("hidden field name");

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Maybe you can try this (assuming ConfigId is a java.lang.Integer):

```
<jsp:useBean id="configId" class="java.lang.Integer"/>  
<bean:write name="configId" property="ConfigId"/>  

<%  
  ConfigDTO = getConfig(configId, null);
%>
```

Also, you would need to add the bean taglib declarations if you still haven't got it:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```